# SVG coordinates shifted

Tags: html, css, svg, path, padding

I'm trying to fit an svg into a div. The svg contains of a single path. I've set up viewBox and preserveAspectRatio correctly, I think, but a part of the path (which is supposed to fit entirely in the svg) is drawn outside the viewBox. Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/groovy354/X5fhb/), and here's the code:

html:

```
<div class='sparkline' class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <svg viewBox="1 1 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M0,10L5,5L10,0"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

css:

```
path {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 0.2;
    fill: none;
}

.sparkline{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
}

svg{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

I see no reason for the line to be shifted to the left, how can I overcome this?

Comment: How is the path supposed to be inside the viewbox if the box is 1-10 and the path is from 0? IMHO, it's drawn correctly. Use viewBox="0 0 10 10".

Comment: `viewBox="0 0 10 10"` instead

Comment: thank you, Anthony! If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it! :)

Comment: @groovy354, why do you think Anthony's comment has a priority? ;-) BTW, he may not receive notification about your comment, because you did not include `@user` tag.

Comment: Good point. Well, I'll accept an answer when anyone will post it :)

Comment: @groovy354, after some grace period I posted my answer ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as expected, but it possibly contains a typo. Provided that the viewBox is defined between 1 and 10, the line with 0 in X or/and Y should look shifted off the box.

Use `viewBox="0 0 10 10"` to fit the line into diagonal of the box.